# How to add specific times in hAxis in Google Timeline Chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I would like to create the following "1a PST" and "1p PST" on the x-axis on a 24-hour interval graph, as shown below:

[image]

I don't see any documentation on the [Google Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) to do so. It seems to always just 'auto-generate' the units on the x-axis.

How would I do the above?